# ionic run android gives me execvp(): Permission denied

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic project, and when I try to run the application using `ionic run android` I get this error:

```
execvp(): Permission denied
Waiting for emulator...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/leoaref/shoofha_app/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

And this is the `ionic info` output:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v0.10.25
```